# Can I get a faunaDB document's json data in one shot with Go API?

Tags: go, faunadb

With Go API of faunaDB, I can define a struct to post the founaDB as follows:

```
type LabelData struct {
    RedirectURL   string `fauna:"redirectURL"`
    Owner         string `fauna:"owner"`
    RedirectCount int    `fauna:"redirectCount"`
}
```

Then I can call Create for the Label Data struct in one shot with the **labelData** as follows:

```
    labelData := LabelData{
        RedirectURL:   "",
        Owner:         "",
        RedirectCount: 0,
    }
    newlabel, _ := client.Query(
        f.Create(
            f.Collection("label"),
            f.Obj{"data": labelData},
        ),
    )
```

My question is, **can I get the data of document** which created above **in one shot to the LabelData type valuable**? Currently, I'm getting it to each element of LabelData type as follows:

```
func faunaLabelInfo(id string) (owner string, redirectCount int, redirectURL string, err error) {
    var data f.Value
    ret, err := client.Query(f.Get(f.RefCollection(f.Collection("label"), documentID)))
    err = ret.At(f.ObjKey("data")).Get(&data)
    err = data.At(f.ObjKey("owner")).Get(&owner)
    err = data.At(f.ObjKey("redirectCount")).Get(&redirectCount)
    err = data.At(f.ObjKey("redirectURL")).Get(&redirectURL)
```

I've expected as follows, but it's wrong.

```golang
var labelData LabelData
ret.At(f.ObjKey("LabelData")).Get(&labelData)
```

Thank you for your suggestion!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

i made full working example based on docker (`docker run --rm --name faunadb -p 8443:8443 fauna/faunadb`):

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"

    f "github.com/fauna/faunadb-go/faunadb"
)

type LabelData struct {
    RedirectURL   string `fauna:"redirectURL"`
    Owner         string `fauna:"owner"`
    RedirectCount int    `fauna:"redirectCount"`
}

var (
    data = f.ObjKey("data")
    ref  = f.ObjKey("ref")
)

func main() {
    var labelId f.RefV
    config := f.Endpoint("http://localhost:8443")
    client := f.NewFaunaClient("secret", config)
    labelData := LabelData{
        RedirectURL:   "",
        Owner:         "",
        RedirectCount: 0,
    }
    // Create a collection to store labels
    _, _ = client.Query(f.CreateCollection(f.Obj{"name": "label"}))

    newlabel, err := client.Query(
        f.Create(
            f.Collection("label"),
            f.Obj{"data": labelData},
        ),
    )
    if err != nil {
        return
    }

    // Get generated label ID
    _ = newlabel.At(ref).Get(&labelId)
    fmt.Println(labelId)

    // Retrieve label by its ID
    value, _ := client.Query(f.Get(labelId))

    var newLabelData LabelData
    _ = value.At(data).Get(&newLabelData)
    fmt.Println(newLabelData.RedirectURL)
    fmt.Println(newLabelData.Owner)
    fmt.Println(newLabelData.RedirectCount)
}
```